# Standalone script onEdit() not working when cell value changes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to put the time stamp every time someone changes anything on a sheet.
This is a standalone code linked to a file via Sheet ID, it works but only when I run the code.

When I edit the sheet, it doesn't automatically update the time.

Any advice?

```
function onEdit() {
 var s = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1Dshq_jln79nDXMVv8O8_BNcpKMf3TrO08aSNQg-abcM"); // bound the file by Sheet ID then open the specific sheet by name

 var ss = s.getSheetByName("H2 OKRs");
 var r = ss.getRange("A1:Y100").activate(); // Check the range of entry

   if (r) { //checks the column
     var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
     if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
       var date = new Date();
       date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+7", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
       nextCell.getCell(1,1).setValue(date);
   };

}
```

UPDATE: Apparently onEdit() doesnt work well as a standalone script so I embedded it back to Gsheet. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: I think opening a spreadsheet by id requires permissions and onEdit is a simple trigger so it can't do things that require permission.

Comment: Required scopes: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets

Comment: @Cooper yeah I granted permission. It ran alright, but the output doesn't update when I continue editing the sheet.

Comment: If you want to have the code in a standalone script, you could use an installed trigger. Not sure why you want to have the code in a standalone, though. Can you clarify this?

Answer (score 1):

See [restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions), `onEdit()` simple trigger runs only when the script is attached to a document and cannot be used in a standalone script. You must have the script embeded into the spreadsheet or be an addon in order for it to fire off when you edit the file.

Comment: Thanks @Vytautas, I think that's the issue. Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: Have the script embedded in the spreadsheet or publish it as an [addon](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/translate-addon-sample) and add it to the spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

please try with

```js
function onEdit(e) {
 
 ...

}
```

Comment: He has a standalone script, so it is not attached to a file. `onEdit()` triggers cannot work then